# Unsatisfied Link Error even if DLL is reachable (java)

Tags: java, dll, native

In our java program we have to use a dll, but we get the error:

**Exception in thread "OPCAgent:OPCVARCHECK5" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: javafish.clients.opc.JCustomOPC.coInitializeNative()V**

As you see, the dll is in the correct place because we do not get the 
no .. in libray path error.

The java we use is **32** bits and the dll is also **32** bits.

We can not call any of the native methods.

```
private static native void coInitializeNative() throws CoInitializeException;
```

We are sure the dll is correct place and reachable from the program because if we change the location of the dll the error message becomes from

`Exception in thread "OPCAgent:OPCVARCHECK5" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: javafish.clients.opc.JCustomOPC.coInitializeNative()`

to

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ./lib/JCustomOpc in java.library.path`

How can I debug the issue? I tried some dll disassembly programs but many of them contains virus, malware etc. Any idea to see the signatures of the dll? The .net reflector fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that your JCustomOPC.dll and jeasyopc.jar files are compatible. Possibly you use different versions of these library files.

Comment: Yes, thats was correct. We were using different versions of java libraries and native libraries.